# Neuvector multi cluster configuration

Tags: security, containers, openshift

**Neuvector** - It is a container security solution .

I have a **Neuvector setup in both Azure(openshift cluster) and AWS environment,** Now using multi cluster option available in Neuvector, I **want to promote the Azure Neuvector setup as master** and want AWS Neuvector setup to join in this cluster.

When I wish to upgrade that to master, It requires "**Master cluster Server" details (hostname or ip address )**, Since I installed on Openshift cluster where can I find or How to get the Master Cluster Server details in my openshift environment.

Can anyone provide me any blog or documentation to get more details on this thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a OpenShift route to expose the neuvector-route-fed-managed service. I guess the service name depends on your installation method e.g. HELM.

Then you can join the cluster using hostname (something like neuvector-route-fed-managed-neuvector.apps.yourdomain.com) and port 443.

Unfortunately it's not possible to create this routs using the HELM chart so I created a [Pull-Request](https://github.com/neuvector/neuvector-helm/pull/84).